# Javascript - calling ASP.NET WebService - The server method 'methodName' failed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

I've been trying to resolve this issue for a while and haven't been successful yet.
I've got a basic ASP.NET WebService which I'm trying to call from javascript as such.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace RandomWebServices
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebServices1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost:2900/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class WebServices1 : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string PieTable(string table)
    {
        return table + " - resultant text";
    }
}
}
```

Simple... Yes?
Then why is it that when I try calling it from javascript I get the following:

> "Error: The server method 'PieTable' failed."

I call the WebService as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CallService() {
    RandomWebServices.WebServices1.set_defaultSucceededCallback(Callback);
    RandomWebServices.WebServices1.set_defaultFailedCallback(OnError);

    RandomWebServices.WebServices1.PieTable("Pie");

    return false;
}

function Callback(result) {
    alert("asd");

    var outDiv = document.getElementById("outputDiv");

    if (outDiv == null) {
        alert("outputDiv not found");

        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("outputDiv found");

        outDiv.innerText = result;
    }

    return false;
}

function OnError(result) {
    alert("Error: " + result.get_message());
}
</script>
```

I am calling the javascript from the following object:

```
<input value="Load" onclick="CallService(); return false;" type="button" />
```

I use AJAX's ToolkitScriptManager object to reference the WebService:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://localhost:2900/WebServices1.asmx" />
</Services>
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Please assist.
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Answer (score 1):

If you are **not** using .NET 4 then you need to do configuration entries to enable script service. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=VS.90).aspx. So make sure that you have following section in web.config.

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/> 
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" 
      type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"
       validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  ...
<system.web>
```

For trouble-shooting, you can look at the stack trace of the exception - for example,

```
function OnError(result) {
    alert("Error: " + result.get_message());
    alert("Stack Trace: " + result.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try applying [ScriptMethod] attribute on the PieTable method, this usually solves my problems when calling webmethods with JQuery.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string PieTable(string table)
{   
    return table + " - resultant text"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found in the past that putting () after ScriptService in the attribute declared on the web service class has *seemingly* solved certain bizarre problems.  No idea why it might have worked but worth a try in your case too.

i.e.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost:2900/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService()]
public class WebServices1 : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string PieTable(string table)
    {
        return table + " - resultant text";
    }
}
```