# What is Ajax status code 8?

Tags: ajax, http, asp.net-ajax

I am using ScriptManager in my ASP.Net page. When i invoke Ajax call, it goes to failed callback. In the response, Status Code = 8 and the message is "The server method *methodName* failed".

What is the meaning of status code 8?

Answer (score 0):

8 doesn't seems to be a valid http status code, Please share your code or try whether this helps - [Javascript - calling ASP.NET WebService - The server method 'methodName' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438199/javascript-calling-asp-net-webservice-the-server-method-methodname-failed)